# Setting all elements with attribute to a certain value

Tags: php, dom, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to set ALL **element's** value of a given XML file that have the attribute "Boolean", to the value of True, I am having a hell of a time figuring out how to do it:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($sxe->asXML());
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@type="Boolean"]') as $node) {
             // something to set the value of $node to the value of "True"
             }
    echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I've tried:

```
$node->{0} = value; // does not actually replace values but doesn't error
$node[0] = value; // errors  Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array
```

Also, if anyone knows, how can I tell DOM to not output the XML using shorthand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to change the `attribute` value, so use `setAttribute`

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@type="Boolean"]') as $node) {
             $node->setAttribute('type', 'True');
             }
```

Update:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@type="Boolean"]') as $node) {
                 $node->nodeValue = 'true';
                 }
```

For your empty tag problem, I'm assuming the code that's generating these tags isn't in what you posted, but when created/adding the new elements, use the empty parameter instead of removing it altogether i.e.:

```
addChild('elementname', '')
```

instead of

```
addChild('elementname')
```

Comment: No, I am trying to set the value of the element. Attribute is only used to find which elements to change.

Comment: Oh, well in that case use `$node->nodeValue = value`

Comment: Correct, thank you sir. Any chance that you know how to tell the DOM to output the XML without using shorthand xml tags?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: When the DOM is spitting out the new XML, it's using XML short tags:(<element />) for empty elements. For some odd reason, the updater application that was built for this project actually requires the full <element></element> versions. Is there a way to declare to the DOM to not use short tags?

Comment: @VikingBlooded Updated in regards to the empty tags

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I'm not creating new XML. I take in XML from a SQL source that's generated by 1 application, I then process that against another DB and fill in the missing information and return a new XML document to be imported. The problem I run into is that, the updater utility that was written by a 3rd party parses the XML out for updating using regex and is expecting there to be am </element> tag for each of the xml elements. When I put the XML out, the DOM automatically uses short tags (<element />) for any empty elements, when in reality, I need that ending tag to be there.

Comment: I'd thought I had a solution by just removing all empty elements altogether and that worked through the updater, but then the DB rejected it because they set up some seriously ludicrous required fields, even for empties.